# Image upload Rest api in codeigniter

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I want to insert image with postman into image folder using Rest api in codeigniter,so where should i create folder "image",Right now i am using following code and i created folder .

```
    echo $filename=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 'images/'.$filename) ) {

        echo "file uploaded";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "something went wrong";
    }
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Are you asking us where you should create your folders on your server? Does your code work? Are you having any issues?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: my code is not working showing "something went wrong", code is not working for me

Comment: Then you need to find out what it is that goes wrong. It could be that the path is wrong or that the script doesn't have permission to save in that folder. It could also be because you use `tmp_name` as filename.

Comment: Check your servers error log to find the actual error.

Comment: You are not using any CodeIgniter Libraries (i.e the file uploading class), so not sure why this is tagged as Codeigniter related. What is your expected path of your 'images/' folder? It is a relative path, so you should be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

check the following.

1. check folder path existing
2. check folder path has write permission
3. check with a smaller size image so that the server upload limit is not crossed.
4. check the postman configurations ie, headers.